# numpy replace repeating values with 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays that loooks like this:

```
arr1 = [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0]
arr2 = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

1. What is the fastest way to compare both arrays and if both have "1" in the same position, figure out which array has the closest "0" looking backwards and replace "1" in that array with "0".
2. Replace all "1"s in an array that are followed by a "1" with "0".

I solved it using iteration, but I am sure there's an easy and much faster solution for this in `numpy` or `pandas`, which I am just only beginning to learn.

Here's an ugly example solution to first problem using iteration:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": arr1, "B": arr2, })
    df2 = df[(df.A > 0) & (df.B > 0)]
    i = 1
    for idx in df2.index:
        while df.loc[idx, 'A'] == 1 and df.loc[idx, 'B'] == 1:
            try:
                if df.loc[idx - i, 'A'] > 0 or df.loc[idx - i, 'B'] > 0:
                    df.loc[idx, 'A'] = df.loc[idx - i, 'A']
                    df.loc[idx, 'B'] = df.loc[idx - i, 'B']
                else:
                    i += 1
            except KeyError:
                df.loc[idx, 'A'] = 0
                df.loc[idx, 'B'] = 0
```

And here's a solution to the second one:

```
    df2 = df[(df.A > 0)].A
    for idx in df2.index:
        if df.loc[idx + 1, 'A'] > 0:
            df.loc[idx, 'A'] = 0
    df2 = df[(df.B > 0)].B
    for idx in df2.index:
        if df.loc[idx + 1, 'B'] > 0:
            df.loc[idx, 'B'] = 0
```

Now do that pandas voodoo and make it all a one-liner.

Comment: your description seems complex - so it may not have easy method in `numpy`

Comment: Can you give an example output, or code for producing the output? The question is complex, so this will help people understand exactly what the question is.

Comment: Please click [edit] and show your [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: Can you craft a **minimal** example? 100 rows is not easy to get the logic. Ideally also break down there logic.

Comment: Also please make your example copy/pastable. Use commas not spaces.

Comment: In your example, when both of the arrays have `1` in the same position and the closest zero is the same in both arrays, you are replacing the second array rather than the first array. Why is that? ie `[1,0,1,0]` and `[0,0,1,0]` both of these have 1 in the same position and both have closest 0 in the same place. Using your code, you end up with `[1,0,1,0]` and `[0,0,0,0]`. Why do you change the first and not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy you could do the following:

```
import numpy as np
def clossest_zero(arr, arr_idx, n):
    return np.maximum.reduceat((1 - arr) * n, np.r_[0, arr_idx])[:-1]

def compare_replace(arr1, arr2):
    A, B = np.array(arr1), np.array(arr2)
    n = np.arange(A.size)
    idx = np.where(A * B == 1)[0]
    idx2 = clossest_zero(A, idx, n) > clossest_zero(B, idx, n)
    A[idx[idx2]] = 0
    B[idx[~idx2]] = 0
    return A, B

compare_replace(np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,1]), np.array([1,0,1,1,1,1,1]))
(array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

---

for the second part:

```
def replace_ones(x):
    x[:-1][(x[1:] * x[:-1]) == 1] = 0
    return x

replace_ones(np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Could you please explain what happens here line by line?

Comment: @Viktor, consider running each line independently to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about better solutions using numpy inbuilt functions, but you definitely don't need sublists to solve this.

Here's my approach to algorithm 1:

```
def func1(arr1,arr2):
#part 1
for i in range(len(arr1)):
    if arr1[i] and arr2[i]:
        print(i)
        for j in range(i,-1,-1): #loop back to start
            if not arr1[j] and not arr2[j]:
                arr1[i],arr2[i] = 0,0
                break
            if not arr1[j]: 
                arr1[i] = 0
                break
            if not arr2[j]: 
                arr2[i] = 0
                break
    return arr1,arr2
```

to summarise, look through the two lists comparing values between arrays, and when you find two 1s in the same index, loop backwards to figure out which to replace.

You only need to compare pairs of values for each algorithm.

The second algorithm is very simple. Just loop backwards, and if two nearby indices contain 1s, replace the latter with a 0.

```
def func2(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)-1,0,-1):
        if arr[i] and arr[i-1]:
            arr[i] = 0
    return arr
```

outputs after applying func1 then func2 to the example arrays given:

```
arr1 = [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
arr2 = [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use numpy methods for your condition. I think should further look for how can I find the index from backward for 0

```
# if both have '1' in the same position
# if np.array_equal(arr1, arr2,): # If both have only 1 and 0
if np.array_equal(np.where(arr1 == 1)[0], np.where(arr2 == 1)[0]): # If they can have other integers compare using indices of 1s
    print("Yes ! Both have 1 in the same position")

    # Find the index of the target value when looking backward
    backward_index_1 = np.where(np.flipud(arr1) == 0)[0][0]
    backward_index_2 = np.where(np.flipud(arr2) == 0)[0][0]
    
    if backward_index_1 <= backward_index_2:
    print("Array 1 has the closest 0 in reverse order")
    # Replace "1" in that array with "0".
    arr1 = np.where(arr1 == 1, 0, arr1)
    else:
    print("Array 2 has the closest 0 in reverse order")
    # Replace "1" in that array with "0".
    arr2 = np.where(arr2 == 1, 0, arr2)
else:
    print("No ! Both don't have 1 in the same position")
```

Comment: As for 2nd problem you can use ChatGPTs solution of getting indexes to replace by 0 using  np.where((arr[:-1] == 1) & (arr[1:] == 1))[0] + 1, then replace those "1"s with "0"

Comment: Tried your method for the first part: getting slighly different result than mine.

Comment: Thanks @Viktor , yes comparison line was not working correctly, I think if you will have only 1 and 0 in array then simple np.equal(arr1, arr2).all() should work. But If you have other integers too than we can compare them using indices of 1s

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to interpret your conditions without a simple, reproducible example (inputs and desired output).

A source of ambiguity is when you say:

> (...) figure out which array has the closest "0" looking backwards and
> replace "1" in that array with "0".

Does that mean that this newly inserted `0` now counts for future determinations of "the closest `0` looking backwards"? If so, it may be impossible to find a vectorized solution.

If, on the other hand, you consider the inputs as immutable, and are looking to make a modified copy with some `1` changed to `0` according to the proximity of `0` in the input, then the following is what you may be looking for:

```py
def zdist(a):
    cc = a.cumsum()
    return cc - np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(a == 0, cc, 0))

def f(a, b):
    a = a.copy()
    b = b.copy()
    p = a * b
    i = np.nonzero(p)[0]
    sel = np.where(zdist(a) <= zdist(b), 0, 1)
    a[i[sel[i] == 0]] = 0
    b[i[sel[i] == 1]] = 0
    return p, a, b
```

Example on simple input:

```py
>>> f(
...     np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,1]),
...     np.array([1,0,1,1,1,1,1]),
... )
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]),
 array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

How does this work?

The first part, `zdist`, computes the distance to the closest `0` to the left of any `1`. E.g.:

```py
>>> zdist(np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]))
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
```

For the second part (function `f`), `p` is the product and is `1` only where both `a` and `b` are `1`. Then, `i` is the indices where both arrays are `1`. And `sel` is a selector based on which array has the closest `0`: (`0: a`, `1: b`).

The result is the tuple of `p, new_a, new_b` (the original `a` and `b` are not modified).

For the second question:

```py
def g(a):
    return ((a == 1) & (np.r_[a[1:], 0] == 0)).astype(int)

>>> g(np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```